# Node js logging - winston.Logger is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am applying logger in node js application using Winston but getting winston.Logger is not a constructor. I am following the link below

http://thisdavej.com/using-winston-a-versatile-logging-library-for-node-js/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the tour : https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Could you add your code so we can help you ?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below code, it should work (it might have happened since you have been using an older code for the newer version):

```
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

    function getLogger(module) {
        const transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            filename: './logs/log',
            datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.',
            prepend: true,
            level: process.env.ENV === 'development' ? 'silly' : 'error',
        });

        // const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        //   transports: [
        //     transport,
        //   ],
        // });

        const logger = winston.createLogger({
            transports: [transport],
        });

        return logger;
    }
```

If you see the commented code, the `new` is what gives an error of not being a constructor

Comment: thanks for reply but after applying this one I am getting "TypeError: logger.debug is not a function" on the "logger.debug('Debugging info');" line

Comment: Can you put your code? How have you required it in your file? Also, did you export the above logger?

Comment: app.get('/app/test', function (req, res) {//To get User
        var hello = 'hi, i am arpit';      
       logger.info('Hello world');
        res.json(hello);
    });.

Comment: Buddy, have you done `const logger = require('./log')`? Assuming the logger code is in a separate 'log.js' file and you just require it where you want to use?

Comment: You will have to give the complete code else it is difficult to point out

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `winston.Logger` has been changed to `winston.createLogger`. Updating your code to use `.createLogger` should fix your problem.

Refer to this documentation https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#usage